# Deriving from `boost::asio::streambuf`

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, streambuf

I'm trying to create my class which is simply public-derived from `boost::asio::streambuf` with some methods added:

```
class my_super_streambuf : public boost::asio::streambuf {
public:  
  void my_super_method();
};
```

But when I simply replace `boost::asio::streambuf` to `my_super_streambuf` there is errors occured:

```
error C2039: 'const_iterator' : is not a member of 'my_super_streambuf'
```

in

```
D:\projects\my_super_streambuf\third-party\boost\boost/asio/impl/write.hpp(199) : 
see reference to class template instantiation
'boost::asio::detail::consuming_buffers<boost::asio::const_buffer,
ConstBufferSequence>' being compiled
```

How can I correctly derive from `boost::asio::streambuf`?

Comment: How do you use `my_super_streambuf`?  What is `ConstBufferSequence` in the failed instantiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with how one derives from [`boost::asio::streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html).  Instead, the resulting error is because the compiler is selecting the non-streambuf [`write(SyncWriteStream&, const ConstBufferSequence&)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write/overload1.html) overload instead of [`write(SyncWriteStream&, basic_streambuf<Allocator>&)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write/overload5.html).  To resolve this, one can explicitly cast an object derived from `boost::asio::streambuf` to a reference of `boost::asio::streambuf` when invoking `write()`:

```cpp
class derived_streambuf
  : public boost::asio::streambuf
{};

// ...

derived_streambuf streambuf;
boost::asio::write(socket, static_cast<boost::asio::streambuf&>(streambuf));
```

---

To understand the issue, consider the declarations of the overloaded function in question:

```cpp
// ConstBufferSequence
template<
    typename SyncWriteStream,
    typename ConstBufferSequence>
std::size_t write(
    SyncWriteStream&,
    const ConstBufferSequence&);

// Streambuf
template<
    typename SyncWriteStream,
    typename Allocator>
std::size_t write(
    SyncWriteStream&,
    basic_streambuf<Allocator>&);
```

If `derived_streambuf` is provided as the second argument, the instantiation of the functions would result in:

```cpp
// ConstBufferSequence
std::size_t write(..., derived_streambuf&);

// Streambuf
std::size_t write(..., basic_streambuf<char>&);
```

As far as the compiler is concerned, the first is a better match as it is an exact match, and thus it is selected.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c60b9b121e71fca9) code that compiles:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// Derive from boost::asio::streambuf.
class derived_streambuf
  : public boost::asio::streambuf
{};

// Helper function to force type.
template <typename Allocator>
boost::asio::basic_streambuf<Allocator>&
as_streambuf(boost::asio::basic_streambuf<Allocator>& streambuf)
{
  return streambuf;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
  derived_streambuf streambuf;
  boost::asio::write(socket, static_cast<boost::asio::streambuf&>(streambuf));
  boost::asio::write(socket, as_streambuf(streambuf));
}
```

Comment: I think one could argue that Boost.Asio's `write()` overloads should be updated to prefer the `basic_streambuf` family of overloads when `basic_streambuf` is a base of the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure there is a "const_iterator" as a public member of "boost::asio::streambuf" ?

i tried these code, and it works:

```
class MyVector : public std::vector<int>{};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MyVector v;
    v.push_back(1);
    for (MyVector::const_iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++) {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
}
```

and also these:

```
class MyBase {
    public:
        typedef int base_int;
};
class MyDerived : public MyBase {};

MyDerived::base_int P = 5;
MyBase::base_int Q = 5;
```

Comment: He talks about `streambuf`, not `vector`